# Left outer join sql not working

Tags: android, mysql, sql, sqlite, select

In my Android app I have a database with two rows of interest.

```
 table1          table2     
 |_id | name |   |_id | table1_id |amount
```

I want to have a query that returns each row in table one **augmented** with the sum of the row amount for each row in table2 with a table1_id that corresponds to the _id in table 1. This is what I came up with so far:

```
SELECT table1._id, table1.name, SUM(amount) 
FROM table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 
USING(table1._id,table2.table1._id) ;
```

This one returns a row with 0 in the SUM(amount) column, also when table 1 is completely empty 
( result |-|-|0| ). I would like the result to be completely empty when `table1` is empty. When there are no correspondences for a particular row in `table1` I would like them to just be augmented with 0.

Any thoughts on improving the query?

Answer (score 1):

You could `group by` before joining:

```
SELECT          t1._id, t1.name, t2.sum_amount
FROM            table1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT   table1_id, SUM(amount) AS sum_amount
                 FROM     table2 
                 GROUP BY table1_id) t2 
             ON t1._id = t2.table1_id;
```

Comment: Why before and not after?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    table1._id, table1.name, SUM(IFNull(amount,0)) 
FROM
    table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 
ON 
    table1._id = table2.table1._id
```